# How to hide div when click on anywhere on the display

Tags: jquery, html

Here My Div #PopupDiv by dafault its in hiding when i click on #Btn1 its display #PopupDiv but whenevere user click anywhere on the display it should be hide

```js
       $(document).ready(function () {
          $('#PopupDiv').hide();
          $('#Btn1').click(function () {
             alert()
             $('#PopupDiv').show();
          })
          $(document).click(function () {
             alert('o')
             if ($('#PopupDiv').is(':visible')) {
                alert('vis');
             }
          })
       })
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" id="Btn1" value="BtnClick" />
</div>
<div id="PopupDiv">
  <p>Hello Popup Grid</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: try this - https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_modals.asp

Comment: hope my answer helps you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this helps:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#PopupDiv').hide();
  $('#Btn1').click(function () {
    alert();
  $('#PopupDiv').show();
  })
  $(document).click(function (e) {
      alert('o')
      if (e.target.id != "Btn1") {
         $('#PopupDiv').hide();
      }
  })
})
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" id="Btn1" value="BtnClick" />
</div>

<div id="PopupDiv">
  <p>Hello Popup Grid</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: your answer is write  but when i click on that  <p>Hello Popup Grid</p>  it should not hide

Comment: No when he clicks on p tag then should be hide

Answer (score 1):

you can simply do like this way, you can use `.stopPropagation()` for this

```js
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#PopupDiv').hide();
    $('#Btn1').click(function (e) {
       e.stopPropagation();  
       $('#PopupDiv').show();
    });

    $(document).click(function (e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      $('#PopupDiv').hide();
   });
});
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="button" id="Btn1" value="BtnClick" />
</div>

<div id="PopupDiv">
  <p>Hello Popup Grid</p>
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: yes.. when you click the button you have open a div, then when you click the document the div has to be hide

Comment: Check my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You can check following code hope it helps: -

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#PopupDiv').hide();           
            $('body').click(function(evt) {
            if(evt.target.id == "Btn1")
            {
            $('#PopupDiv').show();
            }else {
             $('#PopupDiv').hide();
             }
})
        })
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <input type="button" id="Btn1" value="BtnClick" />
    </div>

    <div id="PopupDiv">
        <p>Hello Popup Grid</p>
    </div>
</body> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try as below, this shows your `div` when you `click button` and hides when you click anywhere in page.

> e.stopPropagation - Prevents the event from bubbling up the DOM tree,
>   preventing any parent handlers from being notified of the event.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 var pop = $("#PopupDiv");
  $(pop).hide();
  $("#Btn1").on("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
   $(pop).show();
  });
   $("p").on("click",function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
  });
  $("html,body").on("click",function(e){
   e.stopPropagation();
    $(pop).hide();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <input type="button" id="Btn1" value="BtnClick" />
</div>
<div id="PopupDiv">
   <p>Hello Popup Grid</p>
</div>
```